# How to set the mouse cursor to hidden in a UWP application?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, monogame

In a C# UWP application I use Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null to try and set the mouse cursor to stop rendering which used to work a few windows 10 updates ago but recently the cursor no longer disappears.

What is the correct method to remove the rendering of the cursor?

Also I have tried running the code both in and outside a Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync method.

And I have verified that Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor is null after I set it.

Comment: When I set  `null` to `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor`  that can make the cursor disappear. Does your app is a UWP app or it is a game app?

Comment: What do you mean by is it a UWP or Game app?

It is a UWP title that is a game, but I have not marked it as a game in anyway as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write following code in `App` constructor

```
this.RequiresPointerMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested;
```

Comment: Sadly this has no effect. Perhaps I am missing something else? 

The mouse goes away for a little while (with or without the above code) but returns whenever I move or click the mouse...

Comment: How can I find what is the current cursor type in UWP, C#?